# sharepoint 2010 chart webpart issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010, charts, web-parts

I have 2 web application on my sharepoint 2010 server. with port 100 and 200 respectively.
each web application has site collections. the site of 200 has a list "Job Completion" (simple with date and completion percentage fields).
My client requirement is, add chart webpart on home page of 100 ports web app's site collection. and show chart by using "Job Completion" lists data, which is on another web application. I added chart on required page (on 100 port's site collection home). But while configuring i could not found the option for pass the list url of different site collection (of different port 200)

Can i achieve this without doing code stuff ? 
I stuck over here...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **Data Form Web Part** (**Data View Web Part** in SharePoint 2007) to retrieve data from appropriate list in the other Web application and then configure the Chart Web Part to use this DAWP as its data source.

- [Access Data Sources Across Site Collections or Web Applications](http://mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=957)
- [Adding DFWP using SharePoint Designer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2eODYHp73A)

Comment: Good directions. this is right as per developer perspective.  but is there any way in sharepoint 2010 site collection itself to configure chart with cross web application ? client really do not want any code implementation or to use sharepoint designer.

Comment: @Red Swan: According to http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-a-chart-by-using-the-chart-web-part-HA101889211.aspx#_Toc276035255, the Chart Web Part can be connected to a *list that is located in the same site collection*, so I'm afraid you won't avoid using SharePoint Designer.